# Question about count of empty element (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to make a dataframe which can count repair type.

My initial dataframe is like this :

[image]

With this dataframe, I made a dataframe like this :

[image]

But What I want to do is:

If there is empty string, I don't want to count element. I want to have just empty dict/ So It will be like this :

[image]

Here is a test code.

```
id_ = ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B']
sub_id = ['alpha','beta','gamma','zero','delta','alpha','beta','gamma']
repair_type=[None,'Repair_Type_1','Repair_Type_1',None,'Repair_Type_2',None,'Repair_Type_1','Repair_Type_2']

test=pd.DataFrame({'id':id_,'sub_id':sub_id,'repair_type':repair_type})
test['repair_type']=test['repair_type'].fillna('')
test_2=test.groupby(['id','sub_id'])['repair_type'].value_counts().reset_index()

def count_by_rep(df):
    return pd.Series(df['count'].values,index=df.repair_type).to_dict()

test_2.groupby(['id','sub_id']).apply(lambda x : count_by_rep(x)).reset_index(name='repair_type_count')
```

Can you help me for this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you need `groupby`? `test_2.assign(repair_type_count=[dict([x]) if x[0] else {} for x in zip(test_2['repair_type'], test_2['count'])])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function to only consider rows which have a valid "repair_type"

```
def count_by_rep(df):
    m = df["repair_type"].ne("")
    return dict(zip(df.loc[m,"repair_type"],df.loc[m,"count"]))

out = test_2.groupby(['id','sub_id']).apply(count_by_rep).reset_index(name='repair_type_count')
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your desired output by checking if the dictionary only contains an empty key and return an empty dict in those cases.

Code:

```
def count_by_rep(df):
    s = pd.Series(df['count'].values,index=df.repair_type).to_dict()
    if list(s.keys())[0] == '':
            s = {}
    return s
```

Output:

```
  id sub_id     repair_type_count
0  A  alpha                    {}
1  A   beta  {'Repair_Type_1': 1}
2  A  delta  {'Repair_Type_2': 1}
3  A  gamma  {'Repair_Type_1': 1}
4  A   zero                    {}
5  B  alpha                    {}
6  B   beta  {'Repair_Type_1': 1}
7  B  gamma  {'Repair_Type_2': 1}
```